# Как связать между собой прокрутку внутри разных блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеются два блока с разным содержимым. Ширина блоков одинаковая. Ширина содержимого также одинаковая (больше ширины блока).
 
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы горизонтальная прокрутка внутри любого из блоков вызывала синхронную прокрутку внутри другого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `jquery` :

1. Получаете значение первого дива(или второго, в зависимотси от того, который скроллится) с помощью `$variable = $("div.1").scrollLeft();`(Variable - переменная, 1- класс)
2. Для второго блока делаете так : `$(div.2).scrollLeft(variable);`